# What are watermark in switch ports?

Tags: switch, switching

I have heard this term often in discussion, for example, somebody asks can you change the watermarks of the switch ports? What is exactly one referring to? Searching on the net didn't result any meaningful result.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

They would be referring to the 'high water mark' or the maximum level of traffic that interface has seen.  Clearing the watermarks would just set everything back to 0 and let the interfaces track utilization with an empty history.